# Is socket.io implementation possible inside REST framework?

Tags: node.js, sockets, backbone.js, socket.io

I am building an app in which I provide functionality X, Y and chat.

Lets say that X and Y are non-interactive eg. reading articles - which will work fine with REST (on a node.js server) while chat is obviously interactive so it will work best with socket.io!

**Questions:** 
 1. Is it possible for me to 'switch on' a socket between the server and the user when the user navigates to the chat part of the application? 
 
 2. Can I open up a socket inside a GET request for the url: `example.com/chats/usr_id` on the node.js server? 
 
3. How can this be accomplished inside a Backbone routing framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. Just initialize the connection when the view is rendered (via a controller or script). See socket.io client documentation. You can just connect when the view is rendered and disconnect when the view is terminated. http://socket.io/docs/client-api/
2. You cannot open sockets with a GET request. Socket.io has it's own build in mechanisms for connecting to a socket server. It will start with Web Socket protocol and fall back to Long Polling. You can however use custom url's for unique things. One again, consult the socket.io documentation: http://socket.io/docs/client-api/
3. http://www.sitepoint.com/chat-application-using-socket-io/

p.s. I'd suggest reading up on how Web Sockets work, as you don't seem to have a very strong understanding.

Comment: In part 2 - I wasn't talking about opening a socket using a GET request, I know that its not the way sockets work. All I was saying was whether a socket can be rendered on a particular view (a url basically changes the view!) - and part 1 of the answer covers that. Thanks!